# Access to VPN possible from inside network but not from outside as intended

Tags: macos, vpn, l2tp

I installed an L2TP VPN network on an iMac using OS X Lion Server app. It works fine in testing when I use my wireless access on the network (accessing the external IP address), but am unable to access from other WiFi networks. What did I miss?

Comment: Did you open any ports on your router so that VPN could go through?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You can access the computers in the VPN from your network, but you can't access the computers in the network from a computer connected through VPN, is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Double check your port forwarding on your firewall/Router. Ports 500, 1701, 1723, and 4500 should all be pointed at your server. All are UDP except 1723 which is TCP. Since the VPN connects from inside the network, the ports forwarding is almost certainly the problem.